# Benefits of Heroku Postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Heroku Postgres seems like a nice service, that eases the pain of database management. Personally I have no experience in managing DB clusters, so that's why I like the service very much. However, I was wondering if anyone could provide some experiences with the service, and if the steep price is worth it.

Let's assume I have a Fugu instance with `3.75GB` of RAM, that would cost me `400 USD` per month. How can I justify a price difference of `340 USD / 666%` to a self hosted Postgres instance on a SSD backed VPS with `4GB` of RAM on [ramnode](https://clientarea.ramnode.com/cart.php?gid=1) that would cost me `60USD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have no experience managing databases, so you would need to hire a DBA to do this for you. That would cost more than $340/month, making the price difference possibly worth it.

Comment: No I would not. People (I) can learn. And being a bootstrapped startup with only one employee (me), that's not an option anyway.

Comment: If you're willing and able to invest the time and money to learn postgres, it becomes a lot harder to justify that price difference. You'll have to weight the time you want/need to invest against just forking over money to make the problem go away.